# フォロワー数とフォロー数をリンクで表示させたいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

下記のエラーが出ています。検索したり、relationshipsのコントローラーで初期化の定義してみましたが解決しません。初学者ですので解説もいただけると助かります。

**NameError in Users#show**
Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/rails6-bookers2-debug-ruby3-main/app/views/users/_info.html.erb where line #13 raised:

uninitialized constant User::Relationships

```
        raise NameError.new("uninitialized constant #{candidates.first}", candidates.first)
        ^^^^^
```

Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16

follows
    
  
  
    followers

該当すると思われるコードを記載します。見づらい部分もあると思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

_info html.erb

```
table class='table'>
  <tr><%= image_tag user.get_profile_image(100,100) %></tr>
  <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th><%= user.name %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>introduction</th>
      <th><%= user.introduction %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>follows</th>
    <th><%= link_to user.followings.count, user_followings_path(user) %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>followers</th>
    <th><%= link_to user.followers.count, user_followers_path(user) %></th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class='row'>
  <%= link_to edit_user_path(user), class: "btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
  <% end %>
  </div>



class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to request.referer
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.unfollow(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to request.referer
  end

  # フォロー一覧
  def followings
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @users = user.followings
  end
 # フォロワー一覧
 def followers
   user = User.find(params[:user_id])
   @users = user.followers
 end

 def count(user)
  @count_following = user.following.count
  @count_follower = user.follower.count
 end
end


relationships.rb

class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"


end



user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :books
  has_one_attached :profile_image
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :book_comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :relationships, class_name: "Relationships", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :followings, through: :relationships, source: :follow

  
  has_many :reverse_relationships, class_name: "Relationships", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  validates :name, presence:true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 20 }, uniqueness: true
  validates :introduction, length: { maximum: 50 }



  def get_profile_image(a,b)
    unless profile_image.attached?
      file_path = Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/no_image.jpg')
      profile_image.attach(io: File.open(file_path), filename: 'no_image.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpeg')
    end
    profile_image.variant(resize_to_limit: [a, b]).processed
  end

   def follow(follower_ids)
    relationships.create(followed_id: user_id)
   end
 
  def unfollow(follower_ids)
   relationships.find_by(followed_id: user_id).destroy
  end
  
  def following?(user)
   followings.include?(user)
  end
end

<div class='container px-5 px-sm-0'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
      <h2>User info</h2>
      <%= render 'info', user: @user %>
      <h2 class="mt-3">New book</h2>
      <%= render 'books/form', book: @book %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8 offset-md-1'>
      <h2>Books</h2>
      <%= render 'books/index',books: @books %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 自己解決しました。

Comment: 解決したのであれば、解決に至った情報を自己回答として投稿してもらうと、同じような問題で困った人の助けになると思います。